# Squarespace: block iFrame from attempting to open on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, mobile

I'm currently using Squarespace and use an iFrame on one page.  The iFrame covers the entire width of the page (100% width) and almost the entire height, leaving space at the top for the page navigation buttons.

The iFrame works perfectly on a Mac or PC desktop computer.

However, if I open the page on an iPad or iPhone, the page loads - and then becomes unresponsive.  I'm unable to click on the navigation bar to move to a different page.  The only thing that I can click on that still has functionality is the home navigation button to return to the main page of my website.

I contacted the website that was being used in the iFrame and was told that their program (an app) does not work on mobile devices.

So to summarize the problem: My navigation contains a button "Go to App".  If this navigation button is clicked, the user is directed to the page containing the iFrame.  This page with the iFrame opens on a PC, and crashes on a mobile device.

I can't have the iFrame page crash if someone clicks the navigation button "Go to App" from a mobile device.  How can I add code the navigation button so the iFrame page won't load on a mobile device, and instead gives a message, "This app is currently not supported on mobile devices"?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Not clear what your question is: Are you seeking for a mechanism to detect the device type being used, or how to block your iframe when you know it is a mobile device?

Comment: hi FDavidov - thanks for your follow-up question. I apologize in advance as I'm not familiar with coding - but it sounds like the solution would have to incorporate both concepts: 1) when the navigation button is clicked, the iFrame code determines if the user is on a PC or mobile device, and 2) if the user is on a PC, the page with the iFrame opens, and if the user is on a mobile device, the page with the iFrame does not open and gives a message "This app is currently not supported on mobile devices".

Comment: There are plenty of posts that show you how to detect the device and browser type. Simply ask the correct question and you will get your hands on them. Once you get the device, you can use the suggested solution by Horacio.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the iframe and use media queries for it not to display on mobile. You could also add another div with a `display: none` to show a message to the user when on mobile.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you and FDavidov for your help.  Got it to work!!